# How to make Home Menu( Front Page) use index.php instead of page.php

Tags: theme-development, homepage

I needed a "Home" menu item in my wordpress website, so I created a new page and named it "Home", added it to my main menu item and then from Reading Settings I selected the "Home" as Front Page.

Now the problem is, the `Home` is using `page.php` instead of `index.php`. I really need to get the home page using index.php as I have already designed the front page in my index.php

Could you please tell me how to make the home page use index.php instead of page.php

Comment: have you looked at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)?

Comment: @Milo Thanks for your reply, Yes I looked at the template hierarchy but didn't find any solution from there. But fortunately Bainternet has helped me to solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to duplicate your index.php in to a file named home.php in your theme's folder.

Another way would be to create a new page template same thing (copy index.php into it) and add this at the very top

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Home Page
*/
```

Then head over to the page edit screen and select "My Home Page" from the template drop down

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook.

Add the following code to your functions.php file:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'force_index_template' )) {
    function force_index_template() {
        if ( is_page( page_id ) ) { // Replace page_id with the page id of the home page
            global $template;
            $template = get_template_directory() . '/index.php';
            include( $template );
            exit;
        }
    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'force_index_template');
}
```

**Note: Make sure to replace page_id with the id of the home page.**

Wordpress functions used: is_page, add_action

Answer (score 0):

select home page as Posts page in setting>reading.it'll call you index.php.

1.if you select home page as Front page ,it'll follow page rule,so first search for front-page.php then page.php then index.php

2.if you select home page as Posts page ,it'll follow post rule,so first search for home.php then index.php

[read this may help you](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

So a quick fix would be to backup index.php and rename your original index.php to something like page-home.php, that way you can retain all the changes you have already made.